# Rename tags using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, talend

I have issue with this XSLT script. I want to rename my tags and I have a table that contains tag element with new name. I'm using Talend to get every row and store the names in two variables "generique" which contains new names and an other variable which contains the full path (arbre).

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" 
         doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
         doctype-system="" indent="yes" />
    
    <xsl:param name = "generique" />
    <xsl:param name = "arbre" />
    
    <xsl:variable name="vXpath"  select= "$arbre" />
    
    <xsl:template match= "/">
       <xsl:value-of select="$vXpath"/>
       <xsl:element name ="{$generique}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="0">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

the script doesn't work as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you say `<xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>`, I suspect you want `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.

The way you have it written will only work for a document that starts with `<child>...</child>`.

Note that an absent `select=` implies `select="child::node()"` which is likely what you were thinking you were saying.

Comment: yes if I say instead of this " <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>" this : <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='val']|node()"/> I get this error: it will selected anything.